# FTP using wso2 EI611 vs Apache-CommonsVFS3.6

Tags: apache, ftp, apache-commons-net, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

1. Created a carbon app using WSO2 ei611 using Inbound-endpoint-file.deployed 
   on WSO2.
2. Works good for local files.
3. When given FTP url
   (ftp://username:password@servername/folder1/folder2/folder3), throws warn-
   error WARN FilePollingConsumer Unable to access or read file or directory : username":@"servername/folder1/folder2/folder3. Reason: The file does not exists!
4. Used hexadecimal password in the url(as password had spl chars), still did 
   not work.
5. I changed all FTP folders/subfolders to 'chmod 777', still no luck.
6. I know, EI611 use apache-commons-ftp. The error string, is used in this library.
7. I then downloaded apache-commons-net-3.6 and used the same library and ran
   a FTP client java from WSO2 server machine , and it works fine , in
   connecting to FTP server, using java.

So, where's the problem? Hello, WSO2? care to answer?

Comment: Hi, you endpoint is similar?: <address uri="vfs:ftp://username:password@server/folder?vfs.passive=true"/>

Comment: In some projects I had to use a java mediator that performs FTP tasks because username and password contain special characters, try to change these values.

Comment: Hi Julio, do i need to add the "vfspassive=true" to the FTP URL? I wil try it, but Why?

Comment: This is required when the FTP client and server are not in the same network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding vfs.passive=true did the magic. Thanks for the tip. I did saw this paramter earlier while developing, but ignored it, thinking, it is of no value.